AzureDevops depricating ssh-rsa, however no matter what I do the new rsa-sha2-256 keys won't work
Even after updating the keys still getting the following error:
remote: Command git-upload-pack: You’re using ssh-rsa that is about to be deprecated and your request has been blocked intentionally. Any SSH session using SSH-RSA is subject to brown out (failure during random time periods). Please use rsa-sha2-256 or rsa-sha2-512 instead. For more details see https://aka.ms/ado-ssh-rsa-deprecation.

System details:

OS: Debian 10
OpenSSH version: OpenSSH_9.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
git version: git version 2.20.1

generated new keys using:
ssh-keygen -t rsa-sha2-512
the keys just refuse to work.

What's in your ~/.ssh/config?

Please [edit] your question to describe exactly what commands you're running to set up and use this new key and exactly what error messages you're getting.

There aren't different kinds of keys for RSA with SHA-1 (ssh-rsa) and RSA with SHA-2; they're all the same type, and any RSA key can be used with any signature algorithm.  It's likely that you have some misconfiguration in ~/.ssh/config that forces you to use or prefer ssh-rsa, so including that file in your question would be helpful.

According to this Q&A, you may have previously modified your SSH config to downgrade your security settings for Azure DevOps by adding the following to your ~/.ssh/config file:
Host ssh.dev.azure.com vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

Please remove these lines now and make sure rsa-sha2-256 and/or rsa-sha2-512 are allowed.

This solved my problem. I had previously set global ssh_config to use only rsa as that is what was supported. Thanks a mil!
